# Send form output to an if statement on the same webpage with Flask (python)

Tags: python, html, flask, radio-button

I am trying to create a webpage using Flask that changes its content depending on what radio button the user selects. I don't want to redirect to a whole new webpage, I just want the user to be able to click an option and then have that option be displayed to them. I've tried to make the example below as simple as I could. This is the code from  the python `app main.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def index(choice):
    return render_template('index.html', choice = choice)

def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selection = request.form['options']
        return render_template('index.html', selection)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

and this is the code on `index.html`:

```
<form action="#" method='POST'>
    <p>Two buttons: </p>
    <p><input type = 'radio' name = 'options' value='YES'/>YES</p>
    <p><input type = 'radio' name = 'options' value='NO'/>NO</p>
    <p><input type= 'submit' value='submit'/></p>
</form>

{% if choice == 'YES' %}
    <h1>it works!</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>nothing received</h1>
{% endif %}
```

The issue I'm having is that the else statement is always executed, so I never see the webpage display 'it works!'. I've also tried having the if statement say `{% if choice %}` but it never evaluates to true.
Can anybody with knowledge of Flask see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I needed to set the default value for `choice` to be `None`, and there was no need for the first index function (it did nothing). Instead of directly passing the 'selection' variable to the `render_template` function, I needed to specify that `choice = selection`.
The html code was fine - the issue was just some python syntax I had wrong. The solution is below:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index(choice = None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selection = request.form['options']
        return render_template('index.html', choice = selection)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

def index(choice):
    return render_template('index.html', choice)
```